# About having parallel clubhouse in android cell phone

Tags: application-error

I have tried to use two clubhouses via my android phone by using [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl&hl=en_US&gl=US) parallel app in android cell phone, it is sending the registration code or call directly but as you can see at below, it is hanging on the name registration step:

[image]

If possible, I like to have your comment or answer about the reason of this error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use Parallel Space Lite, be sure to install the separate 64bit as well.